# display MBProgressHUD in the center of the UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, mbprogresshud

when i use the `UISplitViewController`,there are master view controller and detail view controller.
I want to display `MBProgressHUD` in the center of the screen when I in the master view controller.
but how can can i get the view?

`[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:view animated:YES];`

Answer (score 0):

Adding `MBProgressHUD` to the `UIWindow` instance should solve your issue.

`[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:view.window animated:YES]`